# Grails + Java : Attempting to perform implementation of MessagePostProcessor

Tags: java, groovy

I am attempting to implement **org.springframework.messaging.core.MessagePostProcessor** but running into the following issue:

```
ChatMessagePostProcessor is not abstract and does not override abstract method postProcessMessage(Message<?>) in MessagePostProcessor
```

Below is my implementation. What am I missing?

```
import org.springframework.messaging.core.MessagePostProcessor;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;

class ChatMessagePostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("post processor");
        return message;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong implementation of Message. Needed : `org.springframework.messaging.Message`

Thank you.